# .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^mykeyword$ news.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

However, when I open the news.php, the url is still the same, that is www.mydomain.com/news.php instead of www.mydomain.com/mykeyword

I make the following test:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.php [L]
```

I upload 2 files on my server, test.html and test.php and after I type www.mydomain.com/test.html, my php page was displayed, so that mean that I have no problem with my settings. What on earth I am doing wrong???

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+news\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mykeyword [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^mykeyword/?$ news.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: You rock mate... thanks. I was about to start bumping my head against the wall with this problem. Remain here, I will probably post  one or  more questions... Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please send me link to your question in a comment so that I get alert in my Inbox.

Comment: How should I modify the htaccess file if my files were under some directory? let say that my domain is like this: www.mydomian.com/somefolder   Can you help with this?

Comment: Your hosting would have provided you some control panel that has file manager or shell access to let you manage/edit your files.

Comment: The site on which I am working is currently under my site. So I have to modify somehow the .htaccess so the customer can see that it works as he requested. My problem: site is located under www.somesite.com/tempfolder. The code that you post works only if the site is under its domain. While the site is under the tempfolder , nothing work.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Here is the link to my next question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675069/rewrite-dynamic-url

Comment: Here is the chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11486/htaccess-discussion

Comment: Hi Mate. I ask new question, in attempt to solve my problem. Can you take a look on my question? Here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721738/rewriting-php-application-to-get-seo-friendly-urls

Comment: @Zoran: Sure I will take a look as soon as I get in front of my computer.

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule translates *from* the URL supplied by the user *to* the URL seen by the server. Try browsing to www.mydomain.com/mykeyword - you should see the page news.php.

Comment: Yes that is the case indeed. But how on earth my link should be? Should I link to my page like this: <a href=mykeyword.php>mykeyword</a>  ???