# rewrite dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following problem:

`http://www.mydomain.com/articles.php?artid=89`

should become: `http://www.mydomain.com/mykeyword`

I dont mind if the id remain in the url...like: `http://www.mydomain.com/89/mykeyword`

I have the following .htaccess for the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+news\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mykeyword [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^mykeyword/?$ news.php [L,NC]
```

The above part works like a charm.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, Zoran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append these rule at the bottom of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /turkexpo/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(webone\.gr)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/turkexpo/$1 [R=302,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+turkexpo/news\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ mykeyword [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^mykeyword/?$ news.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+turkexpo/articles\.php\?artid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/mykeyword? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/mykeyword/?$ articles.php?artid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+turkexpo/companies\.php\?fairid=([0-9]+)&ehallid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ companies/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^companies/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  companies.php?fairid=$1&ehallid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will forward a URI of `/89/mykeyword` to `/articles.php?artid=89` and externally redirect the opposite of it.

Once you make sure it is working change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Comment: Temporaray, this site is placed under :www.mydomain.com/somefolder     Due the rules RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L] I can't see the changes. How should I modify those two rules so I can see the actual change?

Comment: I think that RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.com)$ [NC] should be something like RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.com\somefolder)$ [NC] I try that but it doesn't work

Comment: any chance that we can meet each other on skype so you can easily see my problem? or it is against site regulation?

Comment: `this site is placed under www.mydomain.com/somefolder` Not sure if I understood this statement. What is DOCUMENT_ROOT of your site? Are you dealing with multiple sites here? I can help you out with .htaccess but I didn't completely understand your setup here. This site supports chat room facility, I can spend few minutes there to understand it better.