# rewriting php application to get seo friendly url's

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have php application which have to be partially rewritten because of the customer request to have SEO frendly urls.

My links are as follow:

www.mysite.com/articles_en.php?artid=89, where I will have to change the url in this:

www.mysite.com/articleTitle

Then I have this url:

www.mysite.com/halls.php?fairid=65 which should become

www.mysite.com/fairname

And www.mysite.com/companies.php?fairid=65&hallid=23 which should become

www.mysite.com/fairname/hallname

You get the idea.

I need a help with the approach. Is it good idea in the tables of the fairs, halls and articles to create a field in the table named for example alias and then to attempt to rewrite the url? Anyone can help me with the steps how to create this script, or to point me to better approach?

I am good at php, but not good at all with regular expressions, so I will be lost on the .htaccess part.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, Zoran

Answer (score 5):

.htaccess something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /url_rewrite.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

database table something like:

```
+------+--------+
| path | url    |
+------+--------+
```

With the path as the PRIMARY KEY.

And a PHP script called `url_rewrite.php` that takes the path parameter from the URL, does a lookup on the database to find the real url and performs an HTTP 301 redirect.

The url_rewite.php page might look something like this (this is pretty much boilerplate code and will need adjusting to fit your requirements - realistically we shouldn't be using mysql_query() any more either - PDO or MySQLi are better and aren't well, deprecated).

```
<?php
// -- database connection and any intialisation stuff you may have might go here ...

//get the path
$sPath = !empty($_GET['path']);

// -> error trapping for empty paths here

//retrieve the "real" url from the database
$dbQry = mysql_query("SELECT `url` FROM `seourls` WHERE `path` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($sPath) . "' LIMIT 0, 1");

// -> error trapping here for query errors here

$dbResponse = mysql_fetch_row($dbQuery);

// -> error trapping here for empty recordsets here

$sRealPath = $dbResponse[0]; # which might be "/articles_en.php?artid=89"

//redirect
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
header("Status: 302 Found"); # for Chrome/FastCGI implementation
header("Location: {$sRealPath}");
die();

?>
```

Comment: not sure that I understand...path will be articlename while the ulr will be article.php?artid=22?

Comment: Also, what my link should be then? Can I keep the existing links, like I have it now that is <a href=articles.php?artid=22>article name</a>

Comment: Here is what I did so far. I created the table seourls with path (varchar 255) as primary key and url (varchar 255). My fields for the moment are as follow: path=add-your-company url= articles.php?artid=89

Comment: now, I am working on rewrite_url.php script. if you see those posts, please let me know if I am on the right path...will post updates here.

Comment: url rewrite is now done. here is the code: [code]    function curPageURL() {
  $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         $path=mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT path FROM seourls WHERE url='$url'"),0,"path");
  return $path;
 }[/code]

Comment: after uploading the above .htaccess file that you post nothing happen. Any advice how can I proceed further??

Comment: This is all just example code to point you in the right sort of direction - the .htaccess simply sets up mod_rewrite so that **any** URL, which doesn't point to a real file/directory automatically redirects to a file called url_rewrite.php with the "path" as a parameter. e.g. `www.mysite.com/fairname/hallname` would redirect to `www.mysite.com/url_rewrite.php?path=fairname/hallname` - that script then has to look in the database table for the path 'fairname/hallname' and redirect to the corresponding `url` value.

Comment: I would like to thank you for pointing me in right direction. However, since it is first time that I am doing this, I have a bunch of questions. Can we meet on chat for couple of minutes? Or if possible, can you post your mail here, so I can send you an e-mail with my questions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to carefully look at the pretty URL of this question on SO and get some idea. Needless to add that SO questions rank very high on Google search results. So taking a clue from SO URL conventions, I suggest you these 3 pretty URL formats:

1. **/articles/89/mytitle** for `/articles_en.php?artid=89`
2. **/halls/65/sometitle** for `/halls.php?fairid=65`
3. **/companies/65-23/company** for `/companies.php?fairid=65&hallid=23`

Now create 3 lookup tables `articles`, `halls` and `companies` like this:

**Table: articles:**

```
+-------+-------+
| artid | title |
+-------+-------+
```

**Table halls:**

```
+--------+-------+
| fairid | title |
+--------+-------+
```

**Table companies:**

```
+--------+--------+------+
| fairid | hallid | name |
+--------+--------+------+
```

Now for above 3 pretty URL handling add this code in your .htaccess under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^artid=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles_en\.php/?$ router.php?handler=article [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)/?(.*)$ router.php?handler=article&artid=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fairid=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^halls\.php/?$ router.php?handler=hall [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^halls/(\d+)/?(.*)$ router.php?handler=hall&fairid=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fairid=\d+&hallid=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^companies\.php/?$ router.php?handler=company [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^companies/(\d+)-(\d+)/?(.*)$ router.php?handler=company&fairid=$1&hallid=$2&name=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Finally have your `router.php` code like this: (sample code)

```
<?php
// TODO: Add sanitization checks for presence of required parameters e.g. handler and lookup failures
$handler = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['handler']);
switch ($handler) {
   case 'article':
      $artid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['artid']);
      $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
      if (empty($title)) {
          #header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
          header("Location: /articles/$artid/" . lookupArticle($artid));
          exit;
      }
      else
         require_once("articles_en.php");
   break;
   case 'hall':
      $fairid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fairid']);
      $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']);
      if (empty($title)) {
          #header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
          header("Location: /halls/$fairid/" . lookupHall($fairid));
          exit;
      }
      else
         require_once("halls.php");
   break;
   case 'company':
      $fairid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fairid']);
      $hallid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['hallid']);
      $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
      if (empty($name)) {
          #header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
          header("Location: /companies/$fairid-$hallid/" . lookupCompany($fairid, $hallid));
          exit;
      }
      else
         require_once("companies.php");
   break;
}
function lookupArticle($artid) {
   // $title = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM articles WHERE artid=$artid"), 0, "title");
   static $articles = array(89 => 'Title\'s A', 90 => 'Title, 1B', 91 => '@Article= C');
   return normalize($articles[$artid]);
}
function lookupHall($fairid) {
   // $title = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM halls WHERE fairid=$fairid"), 0, "title");
   static $halls = array(65 => 'Hall+ A', 66 => 'Hall B', 67=> 'Hall C');
   return normalize($halls[$fairid]);
}
function lookupCompany($fairid, $hallid) {
   // $title = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM companies WHERE fairid=$fairid and hallid=$hallid"), 0, "name");
   static $companies = array('65-23' => 'Company% A', '66-24' => 'Company B', '67-25' => '(Company) C');
   return normalize($companies[$fairid .'-'. $hallid]);
}
function normalize($str) {
   return  preg_replace(array('#[^\pL\d\s]+#', '#\s+#'), array('', '-'), strtolower($str));
}
?>
```

Once you verify that it's working fine uncomment `301 Moved Permanently` lines to get better SEO results.

**PS:** I have used `normalize` PHP function to get all URL text in lowercase, cleaning up special characters and converting all spaces to hyphens.

Comment: @Zoran: Sorry I missed your comment. Pls leave your questions in comments whenever you get a chance.